# HTML DOM span search

Tags: php, dom

I'm having a block of HTML code like the following

```html
<div class="searchDetailPanelRgt">
  <p>
   <span>ID: 10605814  |  Jun 26, '12</span> 
   <br />                                       
   <a href="somelink" target="_blank">View on Map</a>
   <a target='_blank' href='somelink' ></a>
  </p>
</div>
```

I want to access the `Jun 26,12` value using HTML DOM library in php.

```php
$html->find(???)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$html = <<<HTML
<div class="searchDetailPanelRgt">
  <p>
   <span>ID: 10605814  |  Jun 26, '12</span>
   <br />
   <a href="somelink" target="_blank">View on Map</a>
   <a target='_blank' href='somelink' ></a>
  </p>
</div>
HTML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($html);

$spans = $document->getElementsByTagName("span");
$the_first_span = $spans->item(0);
$the_first_spans_content = explode(" | ", $the_first_span->textContent);

echo $the_first_spans_content[1];
```

Comment: Thanx dude...Little bit of modification was needed. bUt it worked.

Comment: Next I need to convert Jun 26, '12' to a UNIX timestamp maybe using a strtotime() call but the HTML is not configured according to that.Any ideas???

Comment: All you need to do is to replace the `'` with `20` (or `19`). How to determine which, I don't really know, but I'm sure there's a solution.